# Check to see if a site is running on wordpress.com or .org

Tags: wordpress

How could i check to see if a site is running on wordpress.com or wordpress.org (self hosted) ?

the site in question is http://www.nsfgirls.com/

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See where the DNS results for www.nsfgirls.com point using a tool like [DNS Bench](http://dnsbench.com). Then use a reverse DNS lookup on that IP address. In this case, you'll see this site is hosted on [bluehost](http://www.bluehost.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[Is My Blog Working?](http://ismyblogworking.com/) is a handy tool, and it shows webhost, some DNS, server signature, etc.